# Is there a way to get/program excel to switch between sheets when you scan a spacific barcode

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, barcode-scanner, barcode

I work for a small business and need help setting up our new inventory management system. I have got the excel document ready and the bar-code scanner inputs the bar-codes directly to cells but I am having a problem. We have over 100 parts and each part has a specific worksheet tab each labeled with a specific part number. Is there anyway that I can code a worksheet that when a part number barcode is scanned say 1234LOCK that Excel will automaticlly go to the sheet labeled 1234LOCK?

Comment: When the barcode is scanned, how would Excel know that? If after it's scanned, Excel puts that barcode in say `Main Sheet`, cell `A1`, you can create a `Workbook Change()` event that could then go to the sheet that `A1` refers to. What have you tried?

Comment: At the moment when a bar-code is scanned it puts the bar-code info in whichever block the cursor is on. I have not really tried much as I am still learning. So to clarify your statement, if say Main Sheet cell A1 says 1234LOCK and I scan 1234LOCK then i can create a Workbook Change that goes to the sheet 1234LOCK?

Comment: To further clarify, I have began to set up a macro, what i would like is once clicked it listens for an input and once received it goes to at inputs sheet. For Example If I click on the select button and scan in 1234LOCK then it goes to sheet 1234LOCK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this in the worksheet module of the sheet that your `1234LOCK` gets put in to when you scan a barcode.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

If Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Then
    lastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ElseIf Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row < Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Then
    lastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End If

If Target.Address = "$C$" & lastRow Then
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = Range("C" & lastRow).Value Then
            ws.Activate
        End If
    Next ws
End If
End Sub
```

I'm assuming your scanning will trigger a worksheet change, and the name goes into `A1`.

Comment: That seems to be getting me in the right direction, It sure helped alot!

Comment: I finally got all that working correctly, i have one last question. I have a Macro set up with the following basic code. Private Sub CommanButton2_click()     Range("C99999").End(xlUp),offset(1,0).select

Comment: I finally got all that working correctly, i have one last question. I have a Macro set up with the following basic code. Range("C99999").End(xlUp),offset(1,0).select the problem is that i need the button to know the last cell entry in both C and D column cells and place the selector in the Column C row that is last row of entry for either columns C or D. Example would be that there is a number in D10 but no number in C10 when I start the macro it needs to place the selector in column C11 even though there is an empty value in column C10 because there is a number in D10? any suggestions?

Comment: @WilliamAaronWinfrey - What are you doing with that cell? [Don't `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/) it.  Is that cell what is essentially going to be the `$A$1`? (The last cell is the one where your BARSCAN goes?)

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: @WilliamAaronWinfrey - I think I get it? See the edit. Does that help?

Comment: I see where you are going, while this would work for a worksheet, i just need it for a separate macro. When Command button is clicked, it will place the selector at the first empty cell in column C , however if column D has values in cells that are further down the list it will place the selector in column C at the row below the last of column D. I have values in other columns that stretch the length of the worksheet so i needs to be specific to column C and D

Comment: @WilliamAaronWinfrey - See my edit.

Comment: ( @WilliamAaronWinfrey - If that works for you and solves the problem, you can mark the post as The Answer by clicking the checkmark left of the post, below the up/down arrows.)

Comment: @WilliamAaronWinfrey - Basically, I added an `If` statement: If the rows in C and D are the same length, set the lastRow to use whatever that row is.  If they're not equal, check if the num. of rows in column C is less than those in D. If so, set the lastRow to be the number of rows in column D + 1.  **Note** I don't have anything for the possibility that column C is longer than Column D - would that ever be the case?